# systemd-resolved: which DNS server is used when no domains are set?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I'm wondering what DNS servers `systemd-resolved` will use when no domains are set. Does it use the `Global` DNS server or use one of the `Link` DNS servers? For example, when there are no domains set:

```
$ resolvectl domain
Global:
Link 217 (vethcad2158):
Link 215 (vethbcc93d0):
Link 213 (veth97a2e2d):
Link 205 (vethea47238):
Link 201 (vethfd64a0e):
Link 3 (docker0):
Link 2 (ens160):
```

And we have `Global` DNS servers configured via `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and also from a `Link` via DHCP:

```
$ resolvectl dns
Global: 10.3.0.21
Link 217 (vethcad2158):
Link 215 (vethbcc93d0):
Link 213 (veth97a2e2d):
Link 205 (vethea47238):
Link 201 (vethfd64a0e):
Link 3 (docker0):
Link 2 (ens160): 10.3.0.21 10.3.0.22 10.3.0.23 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Does `systemd-resolved` default to sending everything to `Global` if there are no domains set, or would it chose to send to `Link 2` for anything? If the Global DNS server (`10.3.0.21`) doesn't respond, will it round-robin through the `Link 2` DNS servers? If yes, when (if ever) does `systemd-resolved` decide when to try the `Global` DNS server again?

This line from the [`systemd-resolved` documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html) seems relevant:

```
If a query does not match any configured routing domain (either per-link or global), it is sent to all DNS servers that are configured on links with the DefaultRoute= option set, as well as the globally configured DNS server.
```

So my guess is that it will use all configured DNS servers, from both `Global` and `Links`. What's the priority? Will it start with `Global` and continue using that until/unless the `Global` DNS server doesn't respond? And the doc says the query "is sent to all DNS servers", does that mean it will actually send a single query to every configured DNS server at once, perhaps taking the response from whichever server responds first?

Sorry for all the questions and thanks for any and all information!

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-resolved-introduction-to-split-dns/) is an interesting article on the topic.  It says:

> ... When there are multiple matches of the same
> length on different interfaces, they are resolved in parallel.

It were great if `resolvectl query` had an option to enable verbose output showing which DNS server in the end provided the resolution to the query, like `dig` used to do...